# fit content in its UIWebview iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, height, epub

I am new to iPad development,

I made epub reader and loaded each page of epub in my webview, when I see my application in portrait mode scrolling is not there, because I have used,

`webview.scalesPageToFit=TRUE;`

When I see my application in landscape scrolling is there even I have used,

`webview.scalesPageToFit=TRUE;`

I do not want scrolling, I want content to fit according to screen size.

**here is my code snippet:**

```
- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {

      if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
          _webview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 770, 960);

      }

    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        _webview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 1030, 705);

    }
}
```

***see my snapshot:***

[image]
You can see there is scrolling in landscape mode and there are lots of spaces left in portrait mode.

In short i want to increase **content size** of UIWebView in portrait and decrease **content size** of UIWebView in landscape then content will fit according to screen size with no scrolling.

**Any help will be appreciated !**

Comment: could you have any solution for landscapemode

Comment: I have increased font size in `PortraitMode` and decreased font size in `LandscapeMode`.

Comment: Suggestion: Try *not* setting the size of _webview.frame on rotation -- the webview should resize itself if you have the constraints set correctly.  I've found that explicitly resizing windows often causes things to break and that it's best to let iOS handle as much of that as possible.